# React Hooks: How do I properly set up useEffect to handle changes to the state of a field in a form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to create a generic form component to take in a Login case, Registration case etc. I am on the Login case lol and I've noticed despite the `usernameError` state reaching false i.e. a user has gone on to enter what is a actual email, the error message will persist:

[image]

I am using [Indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/guides/master/introduction) to do the validation, but the problem is with my component, I would think because the state for the errors is changing in real time that is the problem. But I am not sure how I would connect `useEffect` to my `onChange` handler.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  Loader,
  Dimmer,
  Transition,
  Button,
  Form,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Message,
  Segment
} from 'semantic-ui-react';

import axios from 'axios';

import {
  logInUser,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  userHasNotBeenVerified,
  resetCountNotVerified
} from '../../store/reducers/users/index';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { validateInputs } from '../../utils/index';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

function FormComponent({
  formType,
  match,
  isLoggedIn,
  accountVerified,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  resetCountNotVerified
}) {

  function isLoginForm() {
    console.log('formType; ', formType);

    return (
      <div className="login-form">
        {' '}
        {}
        <style>
          {`body > div, body > div > div, body > div > div > div.login-form { height: 100%;}`}{' '}
        </style>
        <Grid textAlign="center" style={{ height: '100%' }} verticalAlign="middle">
          <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
            <Header as="h2" color="green" textAlign="center">
              Log-in to your account
            </Header>
            {console.log('usernameError ', usernameError)};
            <Form
              size="large"
              onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e, formType)}
              error={formError}
            >
              <Segment stacked>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="user"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="E-mail address, e.g. joe@schmoe.com"
                  name="username"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                  error={usernameError}
                />
                <Transition visible={usernameError} animation="scale" duration={duration}>
                  <Message error content={usernameFeedback} />
                </Transition>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="lock"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                  error={passwordError}
                />
                <Transition visible={passwordError} animation="scale" duration={duration}>
                  <Message error content={passwordFeedback} />
                </Transition>
                <Button color="green" fluid size="large" disabled={disableButton}>
                  Log-in
                </Button>
                <br />
                <Link to="/forgot_password">Forgot password?</Link>

                <Transition
                  visible={accountVerified === false ? true : false}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      color="yellow"
                      centered="true"
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>

                <Transition
                  visible={formError}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      error
                      centered="true"
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>

                <Transition
                  visible={formSuccess}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      success
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>
              </Segment>
            </Form>
            {formError ? (
              <Transition visible={formError} animation="scale" duration={1000}>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <Dimmer active inverted>
                    <Loader />
                  </Dimmer>
                ) : (
                  <Message>
                    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>{' '}
                  </Message>
                )}
              </Transition>
            ) : null}
          </Grid.Column>{' '}
        </Grid>{' '}
      </div>
    );
  }


  function loginSubmit() {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8016/users/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          userHasBeenVerified();
          setTimeout(() => {
            logInUser();
            history.push('/profile');
          }, 5000);
          setUsername('');
          setPassword('');
          setFormError(false);
          setFormSuccess(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setResponseMessage(response.data.msg);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response) {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            userHasNotBeenVerified();
            setUsername('');
            setPassword('');
            setFormError(false);
            setFormSuccess(true);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          }
          if (error.response.status === 404) {
            resetCountNotVerified();
            setUsername('');
            setPassword('');
            setFormError(true);
            setFormSuccess(false);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          }
          console.log('error.response.data', error.response.data);
          console.log('error.response.headers', error.response.headers);
        }
      });
  }


  var Forms = {
    Login: [isLoginForm, loginSubmit],
  }

  var [fadeUp, setFadeUp] = useState('fade up');
  var [duration, setDuration] = useState(500);
  var [name, setName] = useState('');
  var [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  var [usernameFeedback, setUsernameFeedback] = useState('');
  var [usernameError, setUsernameError] = useState(false);
  var [userNameDup, setUserNameDup] = useState(false);
  var [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  var [passwordFeedback, setPasswordFeedback] = useState('');
  var [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(false);
  var [password_confirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState('');
  var [passwordConfirmationError, setPasswordConfirmationError] = useState(false);
  var [passwordConfirmationFeedback, setPasswordConfirmationFeedback] = useState('');
  var [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState(false);
  var [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
  var [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(true);
  var [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  var [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState({});
  var [tokenExpired, setTokenExpired] = useState(false);
  var [responseCodeSuccess, setResponseCodeSuccess] = useState(false);
  var [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => { /* Not sure what to do here */
     setUsernameError();
     setPassword();
  // }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log('e ', e);
    e.persist();
    if (e.target.name === 'username') {
      console.log('username', e.target.name);
      setUsername(e.target.value);
    }

    if (e.target.name === 'password') {
      console.log('password', e.target.name);
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    validateInputs(
      formType,
      username,
      setUsernameError,
      setUsernameFeedback,
      password,
      setPasswordError,
      setPasswordFeedback,
      setDisableButton
    );
  }

  function handleSubmit(event, formType) {
    event.preventDefault();

    return Forms[formType][1]();
  }
  console.log('formType; ', formType);
  return Forms[formType][0]();
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { users } = state;
  const { accountVerified, isLoggedIn } = users;

  return { accountVerified, isLoggedIn };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    { logInUser, userHasBeenVerified, userHasNotBeenVerified, resetCountNotVerified },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FormComponent);
```

So to sum it up how do I have `useEffect` listen for the the changes to the error states for `userNameError` and `passwordError` as I believe that is the problem.

**Update:**

This is a demo of what I thought Iarz meant..

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (usernameError) {
      return usernameError;
    }

    if (passwordError) {
      return passwordError;
    }
  }, [usernameError, passwordError]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for `useEffect` is an array of things to watch so it knows when to fire.  With your current empty array, it only fires on mount (and if you included a return, that would fire on unMount).  When do you want it to fire?  Try changing that to `[passwordError, userNameError]`.

Comment: I'd like it to fire whenever `userNameError` & `passwordError` change depending on what the user enters. Example: a user successfully ands an email being the variable changes to false the error message to cease. Thanks—I am going to give it a try!

Comment: Ah cool.  You're headed the right direction.  If you only want it to change conditionally, at the top of `useEffect` add an `if` conditional and if it doesn't warrant changes, just `return` so it won't evaluate the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to show a demo of what I thought you meant. Could you please check it out when you get a chance?

Answer (score 1):

While you can track changes in inputs by using dependency array in `useEffect`, it might be annoying to have error ui (red backgrounds) even if input is pristine or typed value is valid.

Why not validate form `onSubmit` and avoid `useEffect` here? Imo that's better way to validate form with Semantic UI React.

Comment: Hmm that’s what I was thinking too but thought wouldn’t a user get annoyed as they’re entering correct information they’re still getting the red prompts?

Comment: For me, these statemens are the same: "it might be annoying to have error ui (red backgrounds) even if input is pristine or typed value is valid" and "wouldn’t a user get annoyed as they’re entering correct information they’re still getting the red prompts". Or I am missing somethin?